# Rails: No route matches [PUT] "/blog/2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I am creating blog application in rails. I have a common form for creating and updating blog.

This is view of edit and new.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "form"%>
```

This is view of _form.html.erb blog:

```
        <%= form_for @blog do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "Title" %><br>
        <%= f.cktext_area :article, :placeholder => "Content", :ckeditor => {:toolbar => "MyToolbar"} %>
        <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
```

My blog is creating successfully but I am getting error on update action. This is my edit and update action in blog controller:

```
    def edit
    @blog = Blog.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
def update
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id]) || not_found
    @blog.update_attributes(params[:blog]) 
    redirect_to "/blogs/#{@blog.slug}"
end
```

When I open form from edit view, and click on update button, it throws error:

```
   No route matches [PUT] "/blog/2"
```

My routes.rb is:

```
 resources :blogs
 get 'blog', to: 'blogs#index'
 get '/blog/:id', to: 'blogs#show', as: 'blog'
```

I am not getting where it is going wrong. I tried to add "url: blogs_path" in form_for, it removes the error but doesn't save the edit changes.

Can anybody help me where I am going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: post your routes.rb file

Comment: I would advise you to read the [Getting Started with Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). It appears there are some basic principles (such as routing) that you do not understand yet.

Comment: check if you have 'PUT /blog/:id => blog#update' route when you run `rake routes` in console

Comment: The url should actually be `blogs/:id` if you had followed conventions. DId you write custom REST routes yourself??

Comment: @aromero updated question with route of blog.

Comment: @stevanity if have 'PUT /blog/:id => blog#update' route and i have  written custome REST routes myself.

Comment: resources :blogs is all you need, it gives you routes for all default rails actions.

Comment: Remove those two extra routes. Let resources :blogs only remain.

Comment: @stevanity but i need blog instead of blogs. Is there any way around it?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 but i need blog instead of blogs. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I dont understand why you want to go against conventions. Anyway, using `form_for resource` would automatically generate action URL as a PUT to `/resources/:id` if its an update operation.

So to override this you need to do two things.

1. update your routes to support this:

Add this line to your routes file:

`put 'blog/:id' => 'blogs#update', :as => 'update_blog'`

It is important that you put this line above your 'resources :blogs` call.

2 . specify the URL to which the form should submit:

You will need to create the form tag like this:

`<%= form_for @blog, :url => update_blog_path(@blog) do |f| %>`

Try this and let us know.

Comment: Hey, it is working for update action but as i have common form for edit and new, form is failed to create new blog. It gives error "No route matches {:controller=>"blogs", :action=>"update"...", while creating new blog. Its cause of update url path in form.

Comment: Go against the DRY principle and create a separate form for New .

Comment: oh, so thats the only way? ohk, will do it. Thanks for the solution :-)

Comment: Its not the only way :) You could override your post call to match your liking and you wouldn't have to create a separate form. Try it if you want. But you'll face some hurdles which you can cross easily if you sit and think. :) So its your choice.

Comment: oh. Not getting how to override post call. It would be awesome if you can help or give hint sort of :-)

Comment: Just do what you did with updation. :) `post '/blog' => 'blogs#create'`. Remove the :as helper as you wont be able to use it. Now in the form helper use the URL as `'/blog'+'/:id'` (if you have id.. you wil have to use a conditional statement to do this). Start trying.

Comment: hey, i have id, can you please tell me how to use conditional statement?

Comment: Thats great!! :) Glad I could help.